# О происхождении слова "крестьяне"

Tags: этимология

Слова "христиане" и "крестьяне" только созвучны или имеют общее происхождение?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

О происхождении слова *крестьянин* можно прочитать практически в любом этимологическом словаре. Наиболее полный ответ на ваш вопрос, на мой взгляд, дает Этимологический словарь русского языка Г.П.Цыганенко: В знач.«поселянин», «податной поселянин», «землепашец» слово **КРЕСТЬЯНИН** начинает употребляться с XIV в. До этого оно имело смысл «житель рус. земли» (в противоположность иноверцам, басурманам), а еще ранее, с X в.,— «**христианин**», т. е. «крещеный, принявший христианство» (ср. болг. крестьянин «христианин»). В др.-рус. яз. слово **крестьянинъ** было параллельным к слову христиiaнинъ с тожд. знач. Возникновение слова *крестьянин* одни объясняют как результат изменения звуков, оболочки слова *христиiaнинъ* под влиянием слова *крестъ*. Другие же считают, что нач. звуки **х, к** зависят от разных путей проникновения слова в слав. языки: в заимствовании непосредственно из греч. яз.— **х**, а в заимствовании 
через посредство герм. языков — **к**. Само слово *христианин* восходит к 
греч. christianos «христианин», которое в общеслав. яз. воспринято как 
содержащее суф. -ан-ин наподобие названии людей по подданству, месту 
жительства и т. п. (ср. киевлянин). В действительности же греч. christianos 
образовано с суф. относит. прил. -an-os от собств. имени Christos и значит 
«имеющий отношение к нему, опекаемый им». 
Надеюсь, ответ исчерпывающий: слова **христиане** и **крестьяне** имеют общее происхождение.

Comment: Я как-то давно читала об этом, там параллельно разбиралось слово paganus (кажется, такое написание), которое прошло обратный путь: от нейтрального смысла "сельский" через "языческий" превратилось в уничижительное "поганый", в прямом смысле - некрещеный.

Comment: Похоже, вы читали "Слово о Словах" Успенского.

Comment: Статью в журнале "Наука и жизнь", кажется. Но о-о-о-чень давно.

Comment: а грибы - поганки, неужели тоже от "сельских" жителей Европы произошли? :)

Comment: В конечном счете - да. Опосредовано через слово поганый, которое отровалось от исходного значения и стало означать что-то связанное с нечистотами, а через него и вообще всё плохое, неприятное, испорченное и протящее, марающее....